# JS targeting images in particular div even if they share class

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, string

I currently have images supplied by a PHP loop that I use JS in order to make into a carousel. This gives me a slideshow style selection of images that I can drag into an editor and apply to a page:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
      <?php foreach ($imageResult as $im): ?>
        <?php if($im['type'] == 'content'){?>

          <img class="mySlides" src="<?php echo $im['url']; ?>" style="max-width:200px; max-height:200px;">

        <?php } ?>
      <?php endforeach?>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
</script>
```

This works but there's a problem:

Once the image is selected and dragged into the page area like:

```
<div class="fullContent"  id="fullContent" style="background-color:white; border: dotted 1px black;">
        <!--Image would be here-->
</div>
```

It will still have the class of `mySlides` so when I use the arrows to move between images in the selector it also moves the images saved into the div on the page.

Is there a way to change the JS so that the arrows only move the images contained in the actual w3-content div?

Comment: So you want `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");` to only target items inside `<div class="w3-content">`?

Comment: I believe that's correct, since the images share the class name I only want the nav arrows to affect the ones in that specific div

Comment: OK, I'll provide an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

To this line:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".w3-content .mySlides");
```

And it will work.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to change this properly so that it can show more than one item at once? It currently shows one image at a time, but can I alter the index to show 5 or so at once?

Answer (score 2):

*In response to your follow-up question about showing more than one item at once (posted as a new answer only because I don't have comment privileges yet):*

This ought to do the trick.

The main difference is that any tests for out-of-range indexes occur in a separate function, which is called in a loop to process several different indexes -- and it sets the new values dynamically (instead of always setting them to "x.length" or "1".)

I also used a zero-based array (or, technically, 'array-like object') for the items list and renamed a couple of your variables, but these are just a matter of personal preference.

(Edit: Note that newly displayed images aren't automatically positioned at the end of the list because the HTML sets their order and the script is just changing their style.display properties.)

```
const availableSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".w3-content .mySlides");//Renamed
let slideIndex = 0; // Using 0 instead of 1 (for consistency w/ JS arrays)
showDivs();

function plusDivs(delta) { // Almost identical to your original function
  slideIndex += delta;
  showDivs();  
}

function wrap(tentative, max) { //This is where the magic happens
  let actualIndex;
  // If tentative index is too high/low, resumes counting from the bottom/top
  if (tentative > max) { actualIndex = tentative - (max + 1); }
  else if (tentative < 0) { actualIndex = tentative + (max + 1); }
  else { actualIndex = tentative; }
  return actualIndex;
}

function showDivs() { // Takes no args (acts on global slideIndex instead)
  // Hides all slides
  for (let i = 0; i < availableSlides.length; i++) {
    availableSlides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  // Shows thatMany slides, starting from slideIndex
  const thatMany = 5; // Sets the number of slides to display
  // Calls wrap to keep slideIndex from being out of range
  slideIndex = wrap(slideIndex, availableSlides.length - 1);
  // Calls wrap on thatMany indexes and displays the resulting slides
  for (let j = 0; j < thatMany; j++) {
    let tentativeIndex = slideIndex + j;
    let maxIndex = availableSlides.length - 1;
    availableSlides[wrap(tentativeIndex, maxIndex)].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this answer! I believe it accomplishes everything I need, however, the images are stacked on top of each other instead of in a horizontal line. I changed the last line to inline-block but still the same. Do you know the best way to change that?

Comment: Well, now I have enough points to comment, which is great for me, and you're very welcome. 

Jack Bashford answered your original question acurately, though. I'm not very familiar with the protocols here, but I would think that his answer should count as the "correct" one even if mine is more comprehensive. Unless he chimes in to the contrary, it might be appropriate to mark it as such because I don't think a follow-up answer is usually supposed to count for much on SO.)